# How to compare hive and sql tables

Tags: sql, hive, hdfs

We have created a scheduler that pulls the data from on premise sql server and puts it on the HDFS. Now the problem is we need to verify if the data pushed is correct and is consistent with the on premise data. 
Could you please help me how to compare these tables and their data for correctness . Any thing will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQOOP which also supports validation between a Hive table and a database with the `--validate` option.

Refer to [Sqoop User Guide - Validation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#validation) for more details.